# Python's self.parse - why do we use it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, darkflow

Why and when do we use self.parse()?

I've seen this in few functions when I was going through the code of tensorflow's- darkflow

source where I found this: https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow/blob/master/darkflow/net/yolo/data.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.parse` is simply a variable name you declared in your code, or could be a function you declared in your code.

You do:

```
print(self.parse)
```

Output will be it's value.

Comment: Okay. So, that is just a function which should have been defined somewhere.

Comment: @SujitRoyal Yup, it is.

Comment: so what would this mean - self.parser.tokenise()? Here tokenise() is the function defined in a class. https://github.com/lesley2958/word2vec/blob/master/word2vec.ipynb this is the link of the source code I'm referring to.

Answer (score 0):

`self.parse` calls a function called `parse` (it must be defined in code or in a library) on its own value or output.